# BDD -Quantum framework image validation

Tags: automation, cucumber, bdd, mobile-application, perfecto

I am using quantum framework and using BDD for an app automation. 
I need validate the logo and icon on app but I am unable to find the identifier of these objects through object spy.

Here is my feature and .loc file where the image validation is failing with below error.

```
@sucessfulllogin    
Scenario: login to member mobile app with a Tier 2 member  
   Given I start application by name "SIT1 BCBSM"  
   And I wait for "5" seconds  
   Then I should see image "logo"   
   Then I click on "edit.Username"  
   And I enter "myusername1" to "edit.Username"  
   Then I click on "edit.Password"  
   And I enter "anything" to "edit.Password"  
   Then I click on "button.Go"  
   And I wait for "30" seconds  
   And I close application by name "app1"
```

Locators:

```
edit.Username = xpath=//*[@value="Username"]  
edit.Password = xpath=//*[@value="Password"]  
button.Go = xpath=//*[@label="Go"]  
logo = //*[@class="logo"]
```

Comment: Feature file doesn't help, you should add the html code snippet of the elements(s).

Comment: This scenario is too close to the implementation details to be useful to anyone.

It's not a "valid" candidate for a business scenario, you can extract the language of the scenario and you will see that it's all presentation-related language "show", "click", "logo"...